# Getting DocPad to run in Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, docpad

Has anyone gotten DocPad to run correctly in Azure? I ran into a few problems deploying at first (like CERT_UNTRUSTED) but found I could configure the web role with NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=http://registry.npmjs.org/ and that worked. I also had to either remove bower from the postinstall scripts or add bower to the dependencies (I did the latter since I'm still ramping up on docpad and bower in general and wasn't entirely sure if 'bower install' was needed at runtime).

But I have tried following the documentation on both docpad.org and ntotten.com (that docpad points at) to no avail. That includes defining .deployment with a deploy.cmd that generates static content (which I'd rather not do but tried anyway) and creating a server.js that loads either node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server or node_modules/docpad/out/bin/docpad-server (depending on whether I was running the generation scripts or not.

Whatever the case, I get an HTTP 500 server error. I enabled application and diagnostics logging but I'm not getting any pertinent log files when I view any of the directories via FTP.

In most cases, the web site is deployed properly (according to the git remote hook logs and/or server deployment log in Azure).

So has anyone gotten DocPad to run in Azure (preferably as a dynamic site running directly in Node.js)? If so, how?

PS: DocPad runs correctly locally on my box for me, and I have changed docpad.coffee to always run on port 80 along with other templateData changes.

I also started with the bootstrap+jade template when I ran 'docpad run' initially.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use DocPad on Azure.  My blog uses docpad at deployment time to generate a static site (details [here](http://www.ewal.net/2013/10/10/deploying-docpad-sites-to-azure/)).  I also created a "virtual yard sale" site that runs dynamically in node.js.  I didn't have to do anything really special, and I can't tell you, from the information you posted, what your particular problem is, but you're welcome to look at my site to look for differences between your site and mine.

The demo site is here:

http://forsalebyowner.azurewebsites.net/

That site is directly deployed from this GitHub repo, so you can look here for things like config file, etc:

https://github.com/ervwalter/forsalebyowner

Two notes: First, this uses an older version of docpad, simply because I haven't touched it in a few months and so it hasn't been updated.  Second, I don't use bower.

**Update:**

For debugging, you might want to look at using the Azure log tailing feature to see the console output coming from Node.js.  It's likely that seeing the error message Node is throwing will help you track down the problem.  Details here:

http://coderead.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/streaming-a-node-js-azure-website-log/

and here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Windows-Azure-Friday/Streaming-Logs-from-Azure-Web-Sites-with-David-Ebbo

Note, that log tailing works with node apps also even though most of the examples in the video are ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out more tonight. I took a brief look and see a few things you did a little different (I tried a couple but in different combinations - none all together like you did). I'll also hookup the better logging. That would definitely help (being a developer I'm used to logs - I just wasn't getting any and still new to Node.js).